# How to render directory basename in ZSH terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

Per the Mac OS update to Monterey it indicated the new shell was ZSH:

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
```

After updating I realize that `.bash_profile` is no longer used. After research I found I can reference `.bash_profile` so I can still use my aliases with adding the line:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

The difference I've found for the terminal is it doesn't use `PS1` but uses `PROMPT`. After changing:

```
export PS1='vader ~/${PWD/*\/} '
```

to

```
PROMPT='vader %~%# '
```

it renders the full path. In the `.zshrc` file how can I specify just the ability to render just the current directory or `basename`, so if I have the path of `github/project/node_modules` the terminal would be:

```
vader ~/node_modules%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
PROMPT='vader %1~%# '
```

Now when the current directory is `/Users/vader/github/project/node_modules`, the prompt will display as `vader node_modules%` ; go up a directory and it will become `vader project%` .

Note that this does not include the `~/` from your prior `PS1` prompt. In the shell, tilde is used as a shortcut for the home directory (e.g. `/Users/vader`), and is probably not the best thing to use as an indication that the leading part of the path has been omitted. Square braces are often used for that: `PROMPT='vader [%1d]%# '`

There's a list of available percent substitutions in the *EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES* section of the `zshmisc` man page.

Comment: Ended up using `PROMPT='vader %1~/ '` but your answer got me closer to my goal so I've marked it as the accepted.